# Define report in PowerBI where columns change over time

Tags: powerbi, reporting

I have a HTML file that is generated daily.  Over the past few years we have added a couple of columns to the HTML table in the file.  What I want to do is generate some reports that trend over time based on that HTML, so I want to define a single query for a report, but get a null/default value when the column isn't present in the source.

I have a list of report dates that are available and then I can add copies of the report data to a master report.  The data source however fails to load if the column isn't present in the older reports.  Essentially I read a date from one HTML file as an input, then modify the fetch URL per row for the source to get the historical data.

Is it possible to generate this report without retrospectively changing the old data and adding the column that is missing?  I couldn't see how to do this easily.

Answer (score 0):

I've never done anything like that, but maybe something like this will help.
It checks if a column exists and if it does not then create a new column with a default value.

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMlTSUUpUitWJVjICspLALGMgK1kpNhYA", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [AA = _t, BB = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"AA", Int64.Type}, {"BB", type text}}),
    #"Custom1" = if Table.HasColumns(#"Changed Type",{"MissingColumn1"}) = false
        then Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type","MissingColumn1", each "<n/d>") 
        else #"Changed Type"
    ,#"Custom2" = if Table.HasColumns(#"Custom1",{"MissingColumn2"}) = false
        then Table.AddColumn(#"Custom1","MissingColumn2", each "<n/d>") 
        else #"Custom1"
    ,#"Custom3" = if Table.HasColumns(#"Custom2",{"MissingColumn3"}) = false
        then Table.AddColumn(#"Custom2","MissingColumn3", each "<n/d>") 
        else #"Custom2"
in
    #"Custom3"
```

If this is a suitable solution depends on how data are fetched from the source.